# BaseViewController & UIPageViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, oop, protocols

*Background:*

I am setting up a BaseViewController that inherits UIViewController in Swift for all other ViewController classes to inherit from and hence adopt its properties.

*Problem:*

However, when creating a class that also inherits from UIPageViewController (and BaseViewController) **we have an overlap of inheritance of UIViewController**.

**This leads to the multiple inheritance error. What's another way to model this?**

*Tried:*

I have tried using a protocol method instead such that BasePageViewController will implement protocol BaseViewController, however, I can't find a way to put a function into the protocol for BasePageViewController to inherit. Also, I don't know what the future implications of this may be.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!!

```swift
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    func someFunction(){}
}

class PageBaseViewController: BaseViewController, UIPageViewController {
    //this class overlaps in inheritance to UIViewController
    // Error -> Multiple Inheritance from classes UIPageViewController and BaseViewController
}
```

Comment: You can extend the `protocol` and have your logic inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your `protocol` something like this.

```
protocol BaseViewProtocol {
    func someFunction()
}

extension BaseViewProtocol where Self: UIViewController {

    func someFunction() {
      // Logic
    }
}
```

Then you conform your `PageBaseViewController` to the protocol.

```
class PageBaseViewController: UIPageViewController, BaseViewProtocol
```

Now your `PageBaseViewController` has the function `someFunction` with the logic declared in the `protocol` extension.

However, I think that there are some issues with this approach if you're on Swift 4. https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5581

You should be safe on Swift 5.

Comment: Clearly understood, Thank you!!